# Property to compare in Linq is different by criteria.

Tags: c#, linq

I feel like repeating myself but i don't know how to refactor this.
Linq condition is the same but property to compare is different
(BookingDate ,CheckInDate ,CheckOutDate)

```
    protected void FilterByDateRange(ref IEnumerable<ViewBooking> pObjListBooking)
    {
        DateTime startDate;
        DateTime endDate;

        startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, "d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEndDate.Text, "d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).AddDays(1);

        switch(ddlOrderBy.Text)
        {
            case "Booking Date":
                pObjListBooking = pObjListBooking.Where(item => item.BookingDate >= startDate && item.BookingDate < endDate);
            break;

            case "Check In Date":
                 pObjListBooking = pObjListBooking.Where(item => item.CheckInDate >= startDate && item.CheckInDate < endDate);
           break;

            case "Check Out Date":
                pObjListBooking = pObjListBooking.Where(item => item.CheckOutDate >= startDate && item.CheckOutDate < endDate);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, but I don't know, whether it's a good idea:

```
Func<ViewBooking,DateTime> getDate = null;
switch(...)
{
    case ...:
    getDate = (ViewBooking item) => item.BookingDate;
    break;
}

pObjListBooking = pObjListBooking.Where(item => getDate(item) >= startDate && getDate(item) < endDate);
```